# How to add a image in your drupal.org bio?

Tags: community-official-site

Some [www.drupal.org](http://www.drupal.org) profiles like https://www.drupal.org/u/artofeclipse have a image in the Bio section like this:

[image]

So, I trying to achieve the same in my profile (https://www.drupal.org/u/adriancid) but with another image. The problem is that the site always says this:

[image]

But if you go to see the image it exists in [drupal.org](http://www.drupal.org), but the site always says *Only local images are allowed*.

How can I add a picture in my [drupal.org](http://www.drupal.org) profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a similar experiment (followed by an undo ...), and tried adding this HTML code in the same "Bio" file:

```
<p><img src="/files/logo2104april_0.png" /><br />
<img src="/files/styles/grid-2/public/user-pictures/picture-1962106-1505315670.png" /><br />
Drupaler driven by Views/Flag/Rules/Message/Group.</p>
```

And guess what, it worked!

The bio you can currently see in [my drupal.org profile](https://www.drupal.org/u/pierrevriens) is created using this HTML code:

```
<p><img src="/files/styles/grid-3/public/project-images/rules-140.png" /><br />
Drupaler driven by Views/Flag/Rules/Message/Group.</p>
```

So I *think* you should use an existing image that you know already exists on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org) (such as within `/files/` for both of my sample images).

Ps: note the special image I used from that pictures directory ... looks familiar?

Comment: But how can I upload an image?

Comment: Even though "upload" was not part of your question, I think I can ALSO answer that question ... but before I do, let me first go do some other experiment (have you noticed I rarely post answers I'v not tested myself before???).

Comment: I know what happens, I just see that yesterday I uploaded the image in an issue but I don't save the new issue message, so the image maybe was deleted today. Now I uploaded a new image and save the issue and it works.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer you're too fast ... that is a variation of the scenario I was also going to double check ... so for short: think of a way to upload an image somewhere on drupal.org (on a project page, related to an issue, etc). From then on you can reference that image like you try to do.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the image you are trying to use doesn't exist. If you try to access it directly (https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/expert-back-end-development-Forcontu-badge.png), you will get a 404 error. The image used from the other account is https://www.drupal.org/files/logo2104april_0.png, and it exists.
The markup used from that biography is the following one.

```
<img src="/files/logo2104april_0.png">
Web developer, Drupaler driven by passion, love to navigate new technologies and integrate them in Drupal.
```

In your biography, you should use the following markup, if you want to use the same image used from the other account.

```
<a href="https://www.forcontu.com/en/certificate?field_s_certificado_id_value=D8BD0341&field_s_certificado_codautentica_value=f2e44" title="See the Certification"><img src="/files/logo2104april_0.png" alt="Drupal Certification" title="Forcontu Expert Back-End Development" width="140" height="140"></a>
```

I take the image you see (https://www.drupal.org/misc/watchdog-error.png) is used as placeholder also in the case the referenced image is not found. The tooltip is clearly wrong in that case, but the input filter used from Drupal.org uses that tooltip even in the case the image cannot be found.

As side note, the images attached to a comment in an issue were once uploaded to the /files/issues directory, but nowadays they are uploaded to the /files directory.

Comment: Thanks, is weird, I uploaded the image yesterday, I will made another test. And do you know where I can upload the image to drupal.org?

Comment: I know what happens, I just see that yesterday I uploaded the image in an issue but I don't save the new issue message, so the image maybe was deleted today. Now I uploaded a new image and save the issue and it works.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you don't save the comment on the issue, or the issue, the image is deleted once cron tasks are executed.